# Memory leak when not calling GC.Collect()

Tags: c#, garbage-collection

We've just plugged a leak in our application, where the finalizer queue grew to monstrous proportions. Part of the fix was explicitly calling GC.Collect(). This seems to me rather unnecessarily sloppy, but it works.

Not being particularly familiar with the finalizer queue, I am a tad confused. Is this caused by finalizers taking too long? Does a regular GC collection not run finalizers - maybe it's limited to a certain duration?

tl;dr: finalizers are not run if I don't explicitly call GC.Collect(). I want it gone. What do?

Comment: Where is your code leaking? Show code.

Comment: You are probably not disposing objects that are small and have a finalizer.  The Bitmap class is an example.   You can create a *lot* of them before triggering a GC.  Yes, GC.Collect() is a workaround for that.  Consistently using the Dispose() method or the *using* statement is the fix.

Comment: Afraid I can't show code - it's about 100kloc total, no real idea what's leaking. 

As for dispose, that could be. So calling dispose would ensure the object is not put in the finalizer queue?

Comment: It's likely that Hans' suggestion is the key: be sure to call `Dispose`. You might also find that your program will run much better if you use the server garbage collector. See http://www.informit.com/guides/content.aspx?g=dotnet&seqNum=622

Comment: Assuming that the `Dispose` method is implemented correctly, yes.

Comment: And that turned out to be the culprit. Thank you. Specifically, we had a property returning a temporary disposable object. 

foo.Bar.SetBaz() looks so innocuous, but when each call to Bar creates a new wrapper for some native object, and requires one to call dispose on it, it's a problem.